# React-Native project stuck on :app:installDebug

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio, react-native

Every time I run my react-native project it's stuck in 99%.
I've tried to run ./Gradlew clean and kill adb but nothing works.
I already used my device via usb, genymotion and android studio emulator and it always the same...

> Building and installing the app on the device (cd android &&
>   gradlew.bat install Debug)... Incremental java compilation is an
>   incubating feature. :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:checkDebugManifest :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:checkReleaseManifest
>   :react-native-maps:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :react-native-maps:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee130Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :react-native-maps:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore130Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :react-native-maps:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco130Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline130Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase130Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp3130Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0493Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1024Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1024Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps1024Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1024Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :react-native-maps:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :react-native-maps:prepareReleaseDependencies
>   :react-native-maps:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:compileLint UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
>   UP-TO-DATE :react-native-maps:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
>   UP-TO-DATE :react-native-maps:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :react-native-maps:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
>   UP-TO-DATE :react-native-maps:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee130Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore130Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco130Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline130Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase130Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp3130Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0493Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1024Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1024Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps1024Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1024Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareSAGEReactNativeMapsUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugShaders
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED :app:copyDebugIconFonts
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugSources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugNdk
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:validateSigningDebug :app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE :app:installDebug Installing APK
>   'app-debug.apk' on 'LG-D690n - 5.0.2' for app:debug
>
> > Building 99% > :app:installDebug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here, is the case when your **app-debug.apk** is build under ***"android/app/build/outputs/apk/"*** directory of your project,
so you can directly copy paste **app-debug.apk** in your device and install the apk, or you can drag and drop this apk in your virtual device (Genymotion).
So you can continue your work.

And for the above case, you must have set the path of android sdk in Genymotion, as in below picture

[image]

then restart your genymotion device and then use "**react-native run-andorid**"

inside your project root directory.

Comment: I have install the apk on my device and start the server but the app keeps "loading from localhost:8081".
After the server start the bounding "index.js" reaches 100% and stops.

Comment: Did you start the packager using react-native start.
If yes, then check are your device and system are connected via same network like via wifi.
If yes then also check in developer menu then you provide your system_ip:8081.

Comment: sorry but this "developer menu" is on the phone? if yes where i find this system_ip.

Comment: I started the app using "Debug JS remotely" with Chrome and the app started but too slowly.

Comment: Thats great, you can disable __dev=true, 
Option in dev settings.
This menu will open by shaking your device when your app is open. This will help you.

Comment: I disabled the __dev and reload and it worked, thanks a lot

Comment: Its ok, you can ask if need some more help.

Answer (score 79):

you can kill & restart adb in your terminal

> adb kill-server && adb start-server

and start

> react-native run-android

Comment: this worked, but could you please explain why this is caused, because I have to do this frequently, why adb-server gets hangged or like that, so need to restart?

Answer (score 10):

I was running this on an emulator and ran into this issue. Tried all of the solutions on this page and none worked. Also tried just shutting everything down and restarting it - no luck. This is what worked for me:

1. In android studio, go to the `Android Device Manager`
2. For the emulator I was using, select the grey down arrow on the far right
3. `Wipe Data`

Relaunch the app and it worked fine.

Comment: This worked for me. I hope it will not make error soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Try to change the USB port of your physical device. That worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing one should check is the `USB file transfer` mode.
It clearly says following

```
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on '<Device Name>' for app:debug
```

This requires `app-debug.apk` file to be ***transferred*** first to the device, and if the `file transfer` mode is not selected file won't be transferred and unfortunately, `installDebug` task would keep trying to transfer without failing of timeout or something.

Comment: This was my issue. You have to change USB mode to "File Transfer" on the android device

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue but I was using an actual device connected with USB not an emulator. I know this  is silly but restarting my device and computer did the trick for me =)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, changing the USB cable itself helped. But previous cable was showing that the device is online when using `add devices`

Answer (score 0):

If the same application is already installed through Playstore, try un-installing it first and then execute `npm run android`. This was the issue in my case!